# Setting the network interface for core?

Tags: stellar-core

it is possible to set the network interface that Core is using? Suppose my host has multiple interfaces, which one is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see it binds to any IPv4 address on the specified PEER_PORT and there is no config option.

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/13d36e5bb637fc1b7b7c59bc63599a740bc6f933/src/overlay/PeerDoor.cpp#L30

Same goes for the HTTP command interface, which is either any (if PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT) or just 127.0.0.1.

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/bc3d8410b813ce6975b2c7b78ba8f5ed5b944ea9/src/main/CommandHandler.cpp#L48